# Android + SQLite: MAX returns 0.0

Tags: android, sqlite, max

I am working with SQLite within Android Studio.
Have a table with **REAL** column.
It is the prices of items. 
And I put there some **String** values under from Java.

```
String itemPrice;
```

But they are always decimal, because I use

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

**I am developing it by this really weird way, just because I want to know whether user added a free price or he typed nothing. 

So, in the first case, it will be 0.0

while in the second case, it will be null (or empty string)**

In total, it looks like:

```
21414.0
null
123.0
null
null
```

If I retrieve values from SQLite, according to Lod.d it looks like:

```
21414.0
0.0
123.0
0.0
0.0
```

Then, I am trying to find MIN and MAX values.
Finding of MIN value works great.
But MAX function returns 0.0.

```
public double getTheMostExpensiveOrder(){
    double result = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT MAX (IFNULL ( " + COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE + " ,0)) AS MaxEO FROM " + TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE " + COLUMN_DELIVERY_STATUS + " = " + "\"1\" LIMIT 1;";
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        result = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("MaxEO"));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}

public dobule getTheCheapestOrder(){
    double result = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT MIN (NULLIF ( " + COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE + " ,0)) AS MinEO FROM " + TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE " + COLUMN_DELIVERY_STATUS + " = " + "\"1\" LIMIT 1;";
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        result = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("MinEO"));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

Condition is 100% fine and have a sense in my project.

As for me, I also tried to play with **Double**, but nothing was good.

P.S. If there are no null values, MAX works fine.

**--- ALMOST SOLVED**

**UPDATE:** I've just found that it works with

```
SELECT _itemPrice FROM table WHERE _itemPrice < 1000000000000 ORDER BY _itemPrice DESC LIMIT 1;
```

**So, the problem is SQLite treats null as a extremely big value. Are there another ways to fix it?**

Comment: SQL works normally, just tested it in sqlite. Why do you use `IFNULL` for max?

Comment: really, don't know. maybe because "SELECT MAX (_itemPrice) FROM tablename" does not work for me.

Comment: just tested it on sqliteonline, it works fine. But I have no idea why it doen't work within under Android Studio for me.

Comment: What if you remove `IFNULL` and `NULLIF` from queries? I tested it and it's working correctly too.

Comment: @SergeyGlotov, I've tried it. No good results.

Answer (score 0):

Could this work for your query to return the id and row of the max item from the COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE in your table?

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE) FROM " +TABLE_NAME+")";
```

Comment: It will not work because `MAX` returns not id but maximum value. `SELECT MAX(123, 213);` => `213`.

Comment: Would it work like this? String query = "SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME + " WHERE COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE = (SELECT MAX(COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE) FROM " +TABLE_NAME+")";

Comment: @J2112O java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it. 

It' because of SELECT *

Comment: "SELECT " + COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE + " = " + "( SELECT MAX ( " + COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE + " ) AS TheMostExpensiveOrder FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " LIMIT 1)"; Does not work either with same mistake as above